# how to print a list of all the checked items in qlistwidget. in python

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

How to return or print all the checked items in a QlistWidget?

I am able to print the **selected items** but what i want is to print the **checked items**

So i want to check if the item is checked if yes the system append the checked item to the list and at the end it prints this list.

The code below includes the GUI part and the functions:

- load file
- display header
- display checked items

## code:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    
    import pandas as pd
    
    from PandasModel import PandasModel
    
    import seaborn as sns
    import cufflinks as cf
    import plotly
    import plotly.offline as py
    import plotly.express as px 
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    from plotly.offline.offline import iplot
    cf.go_offline()
    cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)
    
    
    class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
            self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
            self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
           
            self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
            self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
           
            self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
            self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
            
            self.pathLE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
            self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pathLE, 0, 1, 1, 1)
            
    
            
            self.loadBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select File", self)
            self.loadBtn.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)
            self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.loadBtn, 0, 0, 1, 1)
            self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 4)
    
           
            self.displayHeader = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Display header", self)
            self.displayHeader.clicked.connect(lambda: self.print_df_header(self.df))
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.displayHeader, 2, 0, 1, 1)
            
            self.displayDF_checked_header = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Print checked item", self)
            self.displayDF_checked_header.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setItems(self.df))
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.displayDF_checked_header, 5, 0, 1, 1)
       

            
            self.header_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
            self.header_list.setObjectName("listWidget")
            self.header_list.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.selectionChanged)
            self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.header_list, 1, 2, 1, 1)
       

            self.pandasTv = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pandasTv)
    
            self.pandasTv.setSortingEnabled(True)
    
    
         def loadFile(self):
            fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)");
            self.pathLE.setText(fileName)
            df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
            model = PandasModel(df)
            self.pandasTv.setModel(model)
            self.df = df
    
         def print_df_header(self,df):
            savelist = list(self.df)
            for item in savelist:
                qitem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem ( ) 
                qitem.setText ( item ) 
                qitem.setCheckState ( QtCore.Qt.Unchecked ) 
                self.header_list.addItem ( qitem )
            print(savelist)

         def setItems(self, item):
            self.items=[]
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
              self.items.append(item)
              print(self.items.append(item))
        
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
              self.items.remove(item)

# this function allow to print the selected items
         def selectionChanged(self):
            print("Selected items: ", self.header_list.selectedItems())
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = Widget()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cycle through all items and check for their [`checkState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#checkState):

```
def selectionChanged(self):
    checked = []
    for row in range(self.header_list.count()):
        item = self.header_list.item(row)
        if item.checkState():
            checked.append(item)
    print("Checked items: ", ", ".join(i.text() for i in checked))
```

Comment: this was the answer thank you. what if i want to use the data of the selected columns in  ploting

Comment: @PylebPyl3b I don't understand your question. You're using a QListWidget, there's only one column.

Comment: yes the  QListWidget handle list of  items (headers of the dataframe.) where as the dataframe is stored in the QTableView

Comment: @PylebPyl3b so? I still don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: so what i am trying to do is to load a file convert it to **dataframe** and display its content in a **qtableview** then to display the header values in a **QlistWidget**  where the user check the required columns name and perform  functions on it like this function :
here the user check the column names(event_type, event_location)

`def event_location(self,df):
        df_event_location_crosstab = pd.crosstab(df['event_location'],df['event_type'])`